# batch renaming not running on all files

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch script but it works on few files and sometimes not. I don't understand where the error is. Is there any way that i can test that tehscript has run  on all the files.

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.JPG') do (
echo %%a_%%b_%%c.%%d
set $Char=%%b
set $CharF=!$Char:~0,4!-!$Char:~4,2!-!$Char:~6,2!_!$Char:~8,2!-!$Char:~10,2!-!$Char:~12,2!
echo !$CharF!
ren %%a_%%b_%%c.%%d %%a_%%c_!$CharF!.%%d
)
```

**file**

```
NoName_20140603133008976_DONCASTER.jpg
NoName_20140603132507734_DONCASTER.jpg
```

Comment: Just tried and it works perfectly. Post some sample file name where you think it not works. That then can be tested.

Comment: Yes rahul  it works when we have few when i have atleast 10 then few of them does not change.          `NoName_20140603124451995_DONCASTER.jpg', NoName_20140603124452635_DONCASTER.jpg, NoName_20140603124452955_DONCASTER.jpg, NoName_20140603124453475_DONCASTER.jpg, NoName_20140603125236880_DONCASTER.jpg, NoName_20140603131541692_DONCASTER.jpg,NoName_20140603131541932_DONCASTER.jpg,NoName_20140603131919814_DONCASTER.jpg,NoName_20140603132106530_DONCASTER.jpg,NoName_20140603132106850_DONCASTER.jpg,NoName_20140603132107370_DONCASTER.jpg,`

Comment: Hi Rahul can you try these files once and let me klnow if it works fine #

Comment: I can't do the testing on your behalf. Check your script against those files and if you see for any filename it's not renaming, post that file name as comment.

Comment: No Rahul, i have already tested them. the thing is it don't work on some files and when run  this script  again for the same files it works fine.this is were I  am stuck.. i was just wondering where was i going wrong..

Comment: Rahul if your still there can you help me with these the error is micro seconds  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted script works just fine but just going by your posted sample data, if you observe carefully, will find that there exist two duplicate file names as below

```
NoName_20140603124452955_DONCASTER

NoName_20140603131541932_DONCASTER
```

Your script will fail to do the rename operation saying `A duplicate file name exists` since those file(s) are duplicate and those are the same which you are complaining about saying `script won't rename them`.

Hope this makes sense.